# Explanation of the circuit diagram of a PIR sensor activated light

Tags: microcontroller, relay, rectifier, current-transformer, pir

Can someone please explain the operation of this circuit diagram of a PIR sensor led light.

The high voltage "ground" connections in the original diagram have been replaced with connections to mains neutral (N).

[image]

Comment: Which parts of the diagram do you understand? I mean, it seems clear enough to me but, I can't know your skill level hence, you should try and indicate what parts you do understand.

Comment: What kind of explanation you want? It has dangerous unisolated mains connections to low voltage circuits, uses wrong regulator incorrectly which does not work, and will blow up the transistor the first time it is turned off. This kind of dangerous and wrong circuits should not be anywhere for hobbyists to find and trying to make them. If this explanation helped, I can make it an answer.

Comment: @Justme: What "dangerous unisolated mains connections"? There's both a transformer and a relay to provide isolation, and there are even separate grounds for the two sections. The 7905 just needs to be changed to 7805, and add a diode across the relay coil.

Comment: There isn't much to explain. The left half of the diagram is a simple 5V power supply. For the rest, the PIR generates pulses when motion is detected, the Arduino receives the pulses and decides when to switch on the lamp using the relay. BTW, in addition to the circuit changes mentioned above, C1 needs to be much larger than 1 uF.

Comment: @DaveTweed It appears you are correct. The different ground symbols were blurry and I did not see they are separate. But I don't think you still should connect mains voltage devices between 220VAC and ground. It must mean neutral in this case, but for some reason labeled as ground.

Comment: Regulating 12VAC down to 5VDC with a 7805 (not 7905) will waste a lot of power. A  5 volt phone charger supply would probably be preferable. Otherwise a transformer with a lower voltage secondary would be good, or a buck converter instead of the 7805. Or, if you have the transformer on hand with no other use for it, use it, but use the 7805 not the 7905.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Also the reservoir cap is useless. This whole design is like concept art, or like most hobbyist projects, some random similar looking stuff thrown into the schematics to  approximately present it but in practice some other parts used that were found scavenged from junk pile.

Comment: Note that the pinout of the 7805 is different from the 7905 (pins 1 &  2 are swapped), as one might (possibly) expect, the tab (pin 2) is the most negative in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram below is your one with mains-ground connections replaced by N/Neutral connections, and with mains phase shown in red and mains neutral shown in green.

The transformer and D1-D4 at left provide rectified 12 VAC producing about 16 VDC. This is too high for a 5V power supply - a 6 VAC power transformer would be more appropriate - or use a 5V plug pack.

C1 should be at least 100 uF and higher will not hurt.

U2 is a regulator providing +5V. The IC should be an (LM)7805 +5V regulator, and NOT a 7905 which is a -5V regulator.

P2 is a passive infra red detector produces high levels when motion  of "hot things" (such as people) is detected. The response delay and on time are set by electronic circuitry inside P2.

The U1 Arduino microcontroller accepts the low/high signal from the PIR detector on it's signal line A2. An internal program "makes decisions" about what action should be taken. The program outputs a high on signal line D8 "when it has something to say". D8 high turns on transistor Q1, which operates a relay K1 to turn on mains lamp P1.

There should be a reverse biased diode across K1's coil (pins 2,5) to absorb the inductive spike from the coil at turn off.

You can find many [Arduino + PIRexample here](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+pir+example&oq=arduino+pir+ex&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBwgAEAAYgAQyBwgAEAAYgAQyBggBEEUYOTIICAIQABgWGB4yDQgDEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgEEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyBggFEEUYQDIGCAYQRRg8qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) .

A good Arduino + PIR tutorial can be found [here](https://lastminuteengineers.com/pir-sensor-arduino-tutorial/)

[image]